# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse not closing after unfolded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When viewed on mobile devices, the collapsed navbar will be unfolded when clicked on it. But it will not close when I click it again.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="main-nav navbar-right" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!--//nav-toggle-->
    </div>
    <!--//navbar-header-->
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="project.html">Project</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="scrollto" href="download.html">Download</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item last"><a class="scrollto" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
<!--//nav-->
</div>
<!--//navabr-collapse-->
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header .main-nav .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 46px;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item.active a {
    color: #dbdada;
    background: none;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item a {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item a:focus {
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item a:active {
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item.active {
    color: #dbdada;
}

.header .main-nav .nav .nav-item.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I included jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js, I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Your code is working at my end. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No errors. And it still has this problem after I upload the website on server.

Comment: So maybe there's something wrong with js files? @JiteshYadav

Comment: Browser console will show an error if you have an issue with the js file. Can you replicate this behaviour in a plnkr/fiddle? Hard to tell otherwise as same code is working for me. Or if feasible can you give the server url where you are getting this error?

Comment: @JiteshYadav You can view the website on http://vubao.co

Comment: You have a js error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $youziku is not defined". Try resolving this or comment it out for a while and check if the navbar works fine now.

Comment: @JiteshYadav It's an online font library. I commented it but navbar is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the source of vubao.co and found the issue. You have included jquery file twice on line no 168 & 173 (check it on page source). Remove one of the file and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="main-nav navbar-right" role="navigation">
```

instead of this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
```